# TextClock returns different value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timezone

I'm trying to do a sort of clock with some time zones on Android Studio.

I put a TextClock and in my layout this TextClock appears [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl1Bv.png).

But when I run the app, the result is completly different, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBAav.png). It returns a completly different hour..

Here's the XML code of the TextClock:

```
 <android.widget.TextClock
    android:id="@+id/fuso"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="101dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:format12Hour="@null"
    android:format24Hour="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:timeZone="America/Los Angeles"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.206" />
```

What can I do? Why is `android:timeZone="America/Los Angeles"` not working when I run the app?

Have I to add something?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your `android:format12Hour="@null" android:format24Hour="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` two tags

Comment: @JaydipUmaretiya I tried to remove 'android:format12Hour="@null" ' but the hour still different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. Specify `android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"`

```
<TextClock
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#d41709"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```